Problem with kotlin stdlib dependency at runtime
I'm having a problem when trying to use an API where only for this endpoint when I call it I get the following error :
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializationComponents.<init>(kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.StorageManager, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ModuleDescriptor, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializationConfiguration, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ClassDataFinder, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.AnnotationAndConstantLoader, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.PackageFragmentProvider, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.LocalClassifierTypeSettings, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ErrorReporter, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.incremental.components.LookupTracker, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.FlexibleTypeDeserializer, java.lang.Iterable, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ContractDeserializer, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.deserialization.AdditionalClassPartsProvider, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.deserialization.PlatformDependentDeclarationFilter, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.checker.NewKotlinTypeChecker, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.sam.SamConversionResolver, java.util.List, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.EnumEntriesDeserializationSupport, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1087)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at io.opentelemetry.context.Context.lambda$wrap$2(Context.java:224)

    at io.opentelemetry.context.Context.lambda$wrap$2(Context.java:224)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializationComponents.<init>(kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.StorageManager, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ModuleDescriptor, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializationConfiguration, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ClassDataFinder, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.AnnotationAndConstantLoader, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.PackageFragmentProvider, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.LocalClassifierTypeSettings, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ErrorReporter, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.incremental.components.LookupTracker, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.FlexibleTypeDeserializer, java.lang.Iterable, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ContractDeserializer, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.deserialization.AdditionalClassPartsProvider, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.deserialization.PlatformDependentDeclarationFilter, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.checker.NewKotlinTypeChecker, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.sam.SamConversionResolver, java.util.List, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.EnumEntriesDeserializationSupport, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl.createBuiltInPackageFragmentProvider(BuiltInsLoaderImpl.kt:66)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsLoaderImpl.createPackageFragmentProvider(BuiltInsLoaderImpl.kt:35)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.KotlinBuiltIns.createBuiltInsModule(KotlinBuiltIns.java:105)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.FallbackBuiltIns.<init>(JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.kt:362)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.FallbackBuiltIns.<clinit>(JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.kt:368)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.getAdditionalFunctions(JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.kt:192)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.getFunctions(JvmBuiltInsCustomizer.kt:133)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.computeNonDeclaredFunctions(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:309)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:277)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.access$computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:228)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:251)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:251)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:578)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:651)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.getContributedFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:329)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:82)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedFunctions(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:291)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.SubstitutingScope.getContributedFunctions(SubstitutingScope.kt:84)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.computeNonDeclaredFunctions(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:306)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:277)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.access$computeFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:228)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:251)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation$functions$1.invoke(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:251)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunction.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:578)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$MapBasedMemoizedFunctionToNotNull.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:651)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.getContributedFunctions(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:329)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope$OptimizedImplementation.addFunctionsAndPropertiesTo(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:360)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedMemberScope.computeDescriptors(DeserializedMemberScope.kt:115)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:277)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope$allDescriptors$1.invoke(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:276)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:408)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.LockBasedStorageManager$LockBasedNotNullLazyValue.invoke(LockBasedStorageManager.java:527)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.descriptors.DeserializedClassDescriptor$DeserializedClassMemberScope.getContributedDescriptors(DeserializedClassDescriptor.kt:287)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.InnerClassesScopeWrapper.getContributedDescriptors(InnerClassesScopeWrapper.kt:35)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.InnerClassesScopeWrapper.getContributedDescriptors(InnerClassesScopeWrapper.kt:27)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.scopes.ResolutionScope$DefaultImpls.getContributedDescriptors$default(ResolutionScope.kt:50)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$nestedClasses$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:100)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$nestedClasses$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:99)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getNestedClasses(KClassImpl.kt:99)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getNestedClasses(KClassImpl.kt:240)
    at kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses.getCompanionObject(KClasses.kt:47)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getKotlinFunction(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:135)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.findKotlinParameterName(KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.kt:118)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.findImplicitPropertyName(KotlinNamesAnnotationIntrospector.kt:57)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findImplicitPropertyName(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:488)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotationIntrospectorPair.findImplicitPropertyName(AnnotationIntrospectorPair.java:488)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addCreatorParam(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:706)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addCreatorParam(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:695)
    at com.
va:142)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:644)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:539)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:294)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializerCache.java:191)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializationContext.java:599)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:3610)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:252)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    ... 70 common frames omitted
2024-04-03 12:42:52,076 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializationComponents.<init>(kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.StorageManager, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ModuleDescriptor, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializationConfiguration, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ClassDataFinder, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.AnnotationAndConstantLoader, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.PackageFragmentProvider, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.LocalClassifierTypeSettings, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ErrorReporter, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.incremental.components.LookupTracker, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.FlexibleTypeDeserializer, java.lang.Iterable, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ContractDeserializer, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.deserialization.AdditionalClassPartsProvider, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.deserialization.PlatformDependentDeclarationFilter, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.checker.NewKotlinTypeChecker, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.sam.SamConversionResolver, java.util.List, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.EnumEntriesDeserializationSupport, int, kotlin.jvm.internal.DefaultConstructorMarker)'] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializationComponents.<init>(kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.storage.StorageManager, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ModuleDescriptor, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.DeserializationConfiguration, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ClassDataFinder, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.AnnotationAndConstantLoader, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.PackageFragmentProvider, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.LocalClassifierTypeSettings, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.ErrorReporter, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.incremental.components.LookupTracker, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.FlexibleTypeDeserializer, java.lang.Iterable, kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.NotFoundClasses, kotlin.reflect.jvm.i
    at  ....

I have pinged the kotlin reflect and kotlin stdlib versions that look to be the problematic ones but so far I haven't found any fix. I'm using kotlin version 1.9.20 and same for kotlin-stdlib and reflect
